# Unable to sudo: PAM authentication error: Module is unknown

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pam, radius

After a typo in a change to `/etc/pam.d/sudo` no user can sudo at all. The package cannot be modified as it requires sudo privileges, but all attempts result in `rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/pam.d/sudo’: Permission denied` and attemps to escalate to sudo result in `sudo: PAM authentication error: Module is unknown`. The package cannot be removed as it requires sudo. What is there to be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My account was part of the sudoers group, was able to `pkexec vi /etc/pam.d/sudo` and make the appropriate changes to the file as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298239/sudo-command-is-broken)

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. It is generally a good idea to **triple check** changes to system auth files -- lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation where `root` access is required you have 2 options: (1) acquire the `root` password and fix `pam.d/sudo` or (2) boot with the install media with `init=/bin/bash` (or `linux init=/bin/bash` using `LILO`).

If you can't get the root password and must rely on the install media, then you will need to boot the install media, at the `grub` or `lilo` menu choose `Boot Options` and set:

```
init=/bin/bash  (if you are using GRUB Boot loader)

linux init=/bin/bash  (if you are using LILO Boot Loader)
```

Then check that the / filesystem is mounted read/write with the `mount` command. If not rw, then:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

You can then modify/replace `pam.d/sudo`. Reboot or `telinit`. (**Note:** you will need to modify the commands for `systemd`)